# Why css is not working on code igniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am using code igniter on xampp. Recently i made a simple test web page and attached a style sheet but when i load the page in browser my css dosent work (Page dosen't have any effect). I looked many post but none helped.
Below is the web page view code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Web test Site</title>
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $mytitle; ?> </h1>
<p class='test'> <?php echo $mytext; ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
h1{
color:red;
 }
```

Note:
I had placed my css folder outside the application folder.i.e

my webProject:
-application
-system
-user guide
-css(folder is at root)

plsss help me on this i am totally new on code igniter.

Comment: you're using the wrong path to the css file.  if its really at root do somethin like <link href="http://yourdomain.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the folder `css` on your project. 
And read like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url (); ?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the best is what Erman is suggesting, it takes care of the file path automatically. and make sure you set the base url in your config file, WITH a trailing slash like:

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://youmayhavealreadywon.com/';
```

For anything you need to include on the page like css folders or javascript - the file path is relative to your main index.php file. Not the application or system folder.